# Big-O for while loop without predefined number of iterations

Tags: javascript, while-loop, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

I am trying to figure out what the space and time complexity for the function below. The function checks if a the squares of digits of number will eventually equal to 0.

For example, 
`19 => 1^2 + 9^2 = 1 + 81 = 82 
=> 8^2 + 2^2 = 64 + 4 = 68 => 6^2 + 8^2 = 36+64 = 100 => 1^2 + 0 ^2 +0^2 = 1` and the function will stop and return true.

I am having trouble reasoning what the space and time complexity would be for this case. I feel like the space complexity is O(n) since an object is used to store the lookup value and the time complexity would be O(n) as well since it has a reduce function but I am not sure if that's the case.

```
var isHappy = function(n) {
if(n === 0){
    return false;
}

let lookup = {};
let curNum = n;

while(!lookup[curNum]){
    lookup[curNum] = 1;
    const numStr = curNum.toString().split("").map(x=>parseInt(x));
    const newNum = numStr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur * cur,0);
    if(newNum === 1){
        return true;
    }
    curNum = newNum;
}
return false;  
};
```

Comment: Imho, time complexity should be O(log(n)). Note, that while i do have both a reasoning and evidence for that, i didn't fully prove it. I don't know how to put this, but this problem is not at the level, where one solves it with "I feel like [...] time complexity would be O(n) [...] since it has a reduce function". That level of effort/expertise is simply not going to cut it in this case.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your insight.